# Using || in Case switch in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, switch-statement, case

I have a partial that I want to display in a layout only when certain pages use that layout. I've set @page_title for all my pages and thought I could use something like this:

```
<% case @page_title when "Log in" || "Forgot Your Password" || "Create a New Password" %><%= render :partial => "common/hello-world" -%><% end -%>
```

But, the include is only happening on the page titled "Log in" and not the other pages. Are || statements like this not allowed on Case switches? Is there a different way to set an OR statement in the case switch?

Thanks!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
<% case @page_title when "Log in", "Forgot Your Password", "Create a New Password" %><%= render :partial => "common/hello-world" -%><% end -%>
```

Per http://docs.huihoo.com/ruby/ruby-man-1.4/syntax.html#case

Comment: Great! Thanks for including the example with your answer. Those are most helpful!

Answer (score 18):

Use `,` instead of `||` to separate the matches after `when`. See more about Ruby syntax in http://docs.huihoo.com/ruby/ruby-man-1.4/syntax.html#case.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for the link. That documentation looks very helpful.