# Using || in Case switch in Rails wrap in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, switch-statement

follow up question to this question

[Using || in Case switch in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841585/using-in-case-switch-in-rails)

My question is what should be done when wrapping the when's in a method to make the code more readable. returning it directly as you would write it does not work for me?

Example:

```
case @page_title
when "Log in", "Forgot Your Password", "Create a New Password" then #...
```

I'd like:

```
case @page_title
when unprotected then #...
```

My solution according to the answer below would be(use if and elsif instead)

Code before(switch):

```
case stats_category.unit
when StatsCategory::UNITS::SAME_AS_NAME_INTEGER, StatsCategory::UNITS::SECONDS
  if !is_integer
    @error = true
    @message = ""
  else
    write_attribute(:data,value)
  end
when StatsCategory::UNITS::KILOMETERS, StatsCategory::UNITS::SAME_AS_NAME_DECIMAL
  if !is_float
    @error = true
    @message = ""
  else
    write_attribute(:data,value)
  end
when StatsCategory::UNITS::HH_MM_SS
  if !is_HH_MM_SS
    @error = true
    @message = ""
  else
    write_attribute(:data,value.split(":").sum)
  end
end
```

Code after refac (if,elsif):

```
category_unit = stats_category.unit
    if integer_unit(category_unit)
      if !is_integer
        @error = true
        @message = ""
      else
        write_attribute(:data,value)
      end
    elsif float_unit(category_unit)
      if !is_float
        @error = true
        @message = ""
      else
        write_attribute(:data,value)
      end
    elsif time_format_HH_MM_SS(category_unit)
      if !is_HH_MM_SS
        @error = true
        @message = ""
      else
        write_attribute(:data,value.split(":").sum)
      end
    else
    end

def integer_unit(unit)
    unit === StatsCategory::UNITS::SAME_AS_NAME_INTEGER || unit === StatsCategory::UNITS::SECONDS
  end

  def float_unit(unit)
    unit === StatsCategory::UNITS::KILOMETERS  || unit === StatsCategory::UNITS::SAME_AS_NAME_DECIMAL
  end

  def time_format_HH_MM_SS(unit)
    unit === StatsCategory::UNITS::HH_MM_SS
  end
```

Found the answer. my code according to the solution provided by Sergio Tulentsev

Switch:

```
case stats_category.unit
      when *integer_unit
        if !is_integer
          @error = true
          @message = ""
        else
          write_attribute(:data,value)
        end
      when *float_unit
        if !is_float
          @error = true
          @message = ""
        else
          write_attribute(:data,value)
        end
      when *time_format_HH_MM_SS
        if !is_HH_MM_SS
          @error = true
          @message = ""
        else
          write_attribute(:data,value.split(":").sum)
        end
      end
```

Methods:

```
def integer_unit
    [StatsCategory::UNITS::SAME_AS_NAME_INTEGER, StatsCategory::UNITS::SECONDS]
  end

  def float_unit
    [StatsCategory::UNITS::KILOMETERS, StatsCategory::UNITS::SAME_AS_NAME_DECIMAL]
  end

  def time_format_HH_MM_SS
    [StatsCategory::UNITS::HH_MM_SS]
  end
```

Comment: Please show the code that is not working.

Comment: added an example, check if that's what you meant

Comment: @Leventix what is `unprotected`?

Comment: unprotected would be a method that returns an object with a `===` method, and that returns `true` if its argument is either one of the above strings.

Comment: @Stefan added an example to my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You totally can use methods here. Have those methods return arrays [of possible options], which you will then splat.

```
def unprotected
  ["Log in", "Forgot Your Password", "Create a New Password"]
end

def check(page)
  case page
  when *unprotected then 'unprotected'
  else 'protected'
  end
end

check('Log in') # => "unprotected"
check('Buy') # => "protected"
```

Answer (score 2):

It would probably simplest to use `if` and `elsif` instead of a `case`.

But `case` uses the `===` method behind the scenes, so you can define a function that returns an object that responds to `===` the way you want. See [this article](http://www.skorks.com/2009/08/how-a-ruby-case-statement-works-and-what-you-can-do-with-it/) to get an idea.

Example:

```
def unprotected
  o = Object.new
  class << o
    def ===(s)
      s == 'a' || s == 'b'
    end
  end
  o
end

def test(page_title)
  result =
    case page_title
    when unprotected then 'match'
    else 'no match'
    end
  puts "#{page_title} => #{result}"
end

test 'a' # => match
test 'b' # => match
test 'c' # => no match
```